# Servicio en android para escuchar cuando volvió la conexión a internet, cuando la app esté cerrada

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando una app que permita al usuario guardar datos en una base de datos local, y al momento de conectarse a internet, por wifi o por datos envíe los datos al servidor. Ya intenté con service y con intentservice, pero los dos mueren al cerrar la app. Intenté dejar el servicio y que este llame a un BroadcastReceiver, para que este sea el que active la función de enviar datos. Esto me funciona mientras la app está abierta, o en segundo plano, pero si se cierra no envía los datos.

manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

       <receiver android:name=".asistenciaConsultas.estadoRed"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

     <service
 android:name="app.mainPackage.asistenciaConsultas.servicioConexion"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    public class servicioConexion extends Service {
        BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver;
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            mNetworkReceiver=new estadoRed();
            registerNetworkBroadcastForNougat();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void registerNetworkBroadcastForNougat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        }

    }
}


public class estadoRed extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        enviarAsistenciaServidor enviarAsistenciaServidor=new enviarAsistenciaServidor();
        try {
            if(isOnlineNet()){
                enviarAsistenciaServidor.enviarDatosAsistencia(context);
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException | JSONException e){

        }
    }

    public Boolean isOnlineNet() {
        try {
            Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.es");
            int val = p.waitFor();
            boolean reachable = (val == 0);
            return reachable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Android ha cambiado muchísimo, y para bien, facilitando cosas que antes eran hiper complicadas. El caso que aquí expones es un ejemplo. Olvídate del pasado, de servicios, de broadcast y de historias... Para este tipo de tareas deberías usar WorkManager el cual viene ya con una restricción sobre la conectividad, que hará que la tarea se ejecute sólo cuando haya conexión, sin importar que la App esté abierta o cerrada. [Revisa la documentación](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?hl=es-419).

Answer (score 0):

use la libreria WorkManager

```
public class WorkManagerServidor extends Worker {
enviarDatosServidor enviarDatosServidor =new enviarDatosServidor ();
Context context;
public WorkManagerServidor(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams){
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.context = context;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    try {
        enviarDatosServidor .enviarDatos(context);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Result.success();  
}

public static void enviarServidor(Context context){
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest onetimeJob = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkManagerServidor.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints).addTag("tag").build(); 
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(onetimeJob);

}
```

}

y lo llamo desde mi clase o activity con este código, tengo que enviar el contexto por que lo necesito para otros procesos

WorkManagerServidor.enviarServidor(contexto);

Funciono bien.

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o en realidad debería ser una edición a la pregunta?

Comment: Respuesta, lo implemente y me funciono

Comment: Cuando puedas marca la pregunta como respondida.

Comment: ¡No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta! Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.